# I am trying to use an if else loop to check multiple columns for data ranges, how do I make it so that it ignores NAs in my data

Tags: r

I am trying to check numbers in three columns in a data frame and if they're within a certain range, I want a certain output.  I have this part of the code, but one of my tests wants to know if all three are negative, then I get a certain output. My issue is that some of the data in some of the columns are NA.  I want to ignore the NAs in my logic.  Is there a way to do this? A sample of my code is below.

```
if((DataWSGR$RouteType == 7 | DataWSGR$RouteType == 9) & (DataWSGR$SGR > 5 ) & (0 < DataWSGR$`30_Year_SGR` < 5) & (0 < DataWSGR$`20_Year_SGR` < 5) & (0 < DataWSGR$`10_Year_SGR` < 5)) {}
```

The 10, 20, and 30 year SGRs are the columns that will have NAs in them.

Comment: Hi Andy, can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: `0 < x < 0` means?

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the range condition, I think you can just add `| is.na(var)` to the last three conditions:

```
if ((DataWSGR$RouteType == 7 |
     DataWSGR$RouteType == 9)) &
    (DataWSGR$SGR > 5) &
    (DataWSGR$`30_Year_SGR` > 0 & DataWSGR$`30_Year_SGR` < 5 | is.na(DataWSGR$`30_Year_SGR`)) &
    (DataWSGR$`20_Year_SGR` > 0 & DataWSGR$`20_Year_SGR` < 5 | is.na(DataWSGR$`20_Year_SGR`)) &
    (DataWSGR$`10_Year_SGR` > 0 & DataWSGR$`10_Year_SGR` < 5 | is.na(DataWSGR$`10_Year_SGR`))) {
}
```

If `DataWSGR` has more than one row, the above will throw an error.

Here is a reproducible example for doing this in a `for` loop:

```
df <- data.frame(
  route_type = c(7, 6, 9),
  sgr = c(6, 3, 6),
  sgr_30 = c(3, 1, NA),
  sgr_20 = c(1, 1, NA),
  sgr_10 = c(2, 1, NA)
)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (
    (df$route_type[i] == 7 | df$route_type[i] == 9) &
    (df$sgr[i] > 5) &
    (df$sgr_30[1] > 0 & df$sgr_30[i] < 5 | is.na(df$sgr_30[i])) &
    (df$sgr_20[1] > 0 & df$sgr_20[i] < 5 | is.na(df$sgr_20[i])) &
    (df$sgr_10[1] > 0 & df$sgr_10[i] < 5 | is.na(df$sgr_10[i]))
  ) {
    print(paste("In range in row", i))
  }
}
```